# How to break up a multidimensional array that has been loaded w/ load->vars()

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, codeigniter-2, loadvars

This array was passed by `$this->load->var($data)` with some global variables. I need to extract the array below from the associative array that `var` has instantiated for me. That array currently looks like this: Notice the multidimensional array below.

```
 Dump => array(1) {
  [9] => array(1) {
    [0] => object(stdClass)#21 (8) {
      ["day"] => string(2) "09"
      ["eventContent"] => string(14) "slug ok"
      ["eventTitle"] => string(4) "Slug"
      ["id"] => string(1) "4"
      ["user"] => string(3) "CZL"
      ["user_id"] => string(1) "1"
      ["slug"] => string(4) "Slug"
      ["eventDate"] => string(10) "2013-07-09"
    }
  }
}
```

I  need to convert it to look like this:
Notice the single dimension array below.

```
Dump => array(1) {
  [0] => object(stdClass)#21 (7) {
      ["day"] => string(2) "09"
      ["eventContent"] => string(14) "slug ok"
      ["eventTitle"] => string(4) "Slug"
      ["id"] => string(1) "4"
      ["user"] => string(3) "CZL"
      ["user_id"] => string(1) "1"
      ["slug"] => string(4) "Slug"
      ["eventDate"] => string(10) "2013-07-09"
  }
}
```

Besides converting the multi to a single, is there a way I could call the singular array from the multidimensional one?

I am using a foreach on the multidimensional array, but it's outputting incorrectly. Here is what I'm using. `calendars` is the array above that i am passing to it.

```
foreach ($calendars as $calendar) {
        $url = calendar_link($calendar);
        $string .= '<li>';
        $string .= '<h3>' . anchor($url, e($calendar->eventTitle)) .  ' ›</h3>';
        $string .= '<p class="pubdate">' . e($calendar->eventDate) . '</p>';
        $string .= '</li>';
    }

function calendar_link($calendar){
return 'calendar/event/' . intval($calendar->id) . '/' . e($calendar->slug);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the multidimensional array really looks exactly like your dump, then you should be able to do somthing like:

`$calendar_single = $calendars[9]; // I dont know why you get 9 as array key here?`

Then you should have an array with one object.

If you want to reach the object directly, try this:

`$calendar_object = $calendars[9][0];`

And then you foreach should work:

`foreach ($calendar_object as $calendar) { ...`

Not the nicest solution and it wont work if your array key (9) will change..

You could also try a more general solution that could work regardless of array key indexes:

```
foreach($multi as $single){
    foreach($single as $object){
        foreach($object as $calendar){
            // YOUR CODE HERE
            calendar_link($calendar); // ETC…
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't know why I'm getting a 9, I have dumped 3 std objects and they count down from 9 -> 6 -> then 0 for my last object. but thanks for your answer, I will have to work on this a little more. maybe it's the key that's assigned by the load->var($calendar)

Comment: Updated my answer with a more general approach that should work regardless of array key indexes.. Hope you get it working..

Comment: Thank you, after a good night's rest, all was needed was an extra level of `foreach` to pick up the array I needed.